# On initial page load mounted not working for VUE3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

The issue I have is currently on mounted even when my `data?.information` has a scroll height greater than client height meaning `isTextTruncated.value` is `true` on initial page load this doesn't work but as soon as I click around it triggers which I assume is the watcher working but how do I ensure it also works on mounted?

SCRIPT:

```
const information = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

watch(query, () => {
  // Use watch to monitor changes in the 'information' ref
  informationRefStatus(),
  { immediate: true }
})

function informationRefStatus() {
  if (information.value) {
    const element = information.value
    return isTextTruncated.value = element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight
  }
}
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div>
  <div ref="information" :class="isExpanded ? 'truncate' : ''">
    {{ data?.information }}
  </div>
  <span
    v-if="isTextTruncated"
    @click="isExpanded = !isExpanded"
  >
    {{ toggleCtaLabel }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The initialize in onMounted is not needed, because immediate:true will fire the watcher once on rendering.

Comment: Also consider using https://vueuse.org/functions.html#category=Elements composables for the heights.

Comment: Thanks @MrSpt I've removed onMounted (edited question above as well) but it still requires me to click in the console before it will load, any thoughts?

Comment: I can only guess that it has something to do with the query you're watching. Hard to tell without actually providing something to test.